# Should all my asp.net MVC controllers use Web APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-api, web

The thing that I don't understand is the prioritization between MVC Controllers and Web APIs.

Consider I want to make a website. I can either program to APIs and for the presentational layer, force the MVC controllers to consume the APIs OR simply go with controllers and don't bother with the APIs for the time being.

What is the thing that I have to really consider? is there anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: "force the MVC controllers to consume the APIs OR simply go with controllers and don't bother with the APIs for the time being." This is interesting. Consider _how_ you would consume the APIs, via JavaScript rendered by the MVC views or by using a CLR httpclient to call your own server from that server. Obviously the latter would be silly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Controller` for rendering the `views`. In AP.NET MVC, it basically works similar to that of `WEB-API`, but it's derived from `APIController` class instead of `Controller` class. As the name states Web API, controllers meant to handle the serialised requests.
You can also create a Web API project using the "Web API" template. The Web API template uses ASP.NET MVC to provide API help pages. In general, you don't need to know ASP.NET MVC to use Web API.
So in your case, you can opt to work with MVC, since you need to return some views to return. 
Consider `Web-API` only when you need to work with some external clients consume using `HTTP` requests.

Refer the links below for a detailed official description.
For [Web-API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/)
For [MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc5)